# I want to add tests for seeds to know that seeds are not broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, seeding

What is the best way to test for seeds, and are there examples/tutorials?  I have looked and have come up short on something that is actually useful for a newbie.

Also, what is the proper name for a test like this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'test for seeds'.  Do you mean fixture data? Pseudorandom seeds?  Something else?

Comment: normally seeds are used to bootsrap your dev env with some quick data, So I personally believe you done need to write test for seeds. And also only write test for the places they required. Do not overkill your app with test. And I use migrations to populate data as it allows to roll back etc, which doesnot support by seed

Comment: I think that a simple test that makes sure that the seeds can be run (they are not outdated) can be really useful. It is very common to need them in a hurry and see they failing.